# How to take web app offline while publishing?

Tags: azure, publish, azure-web-app-service

Very often, when I hit *Publish* in VS13, I get the site to compile but when uploading I get the error saying that a file is busy.

> Updating file (MyAzureSite\PrecompiledApp.config).
>   C:...\v12.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(4255,5):
>   Error ERROR_FILE_IN_USE: Web deployment task failed.
>   (The file 'PrecompiledApp.config' is in use.
>   Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_FILE_IN_USE.)

When I follow the link provided, it's suggested that I should go for *enabling the appOffline rule*. "Sure!", I think to myself. But **how**?! I've googled it, only to get a bunch of hits on the file that's supposed to replace the site while publishing. However, I get no info on how to get rid of my little problem.

I went the easy way and downloaded a publishing profile from my Azure web site and now I'm using it (you know, <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>).

Right now I resolve the problem by going to the portal for Azure and manually take the site off-line. Then I can publish and after that I take the site on-line. Highly impractical and painfully tedious.

What is causing this and how do I kill it?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You actually configure it in the publishing profile (.pubxml). Just add the element to the PropertyGroup like this:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <EnableMSDeployAppOffline>true</EnableMSDeployAppOffline>
  ...
</PropertyGroup>
```

More in this [MSDN document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942158.aspx#app_offline)

Comment: It wasn't automatically found by intellisense so I had to type in all the thing by hand. Strange... And I also noticed that the first element (i.e. *<WebPublishMethod>*) wasn't recognized, neither. It's underlined by blue wave... Comment on that? I've posted [another question on that subject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20921790/correct-tags-in-pubxml-not-recognized-by-intellisense).

Comment: VS uses MsBuild Schema to validate the file. You may see several warnings but you can ignore them. People were complaining about this  [long ago](http://sstjean.blogspot.com/2007/04/visual-studio-warning-element-in.html)

Comment: sadly, this solution only works when publishing directly from VS; but the continuous deployment doesn't respect the settings either in the .pubxml file or passed in as command line arguments to MSBuild

Comment: @MatthewBelk did you ever figure out how to get this working with CI implementation? Having same troubles here...

Comment: You could try this on CI: http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/deploying-application-packages/taking-an-application-offline-before-publishing

Comment: With VS2015 I get an error saying: [publishing profile] *has invalid child element 'EnableMSDeployAppOffline'*.

Comment: How can I use my custom app offline template for this job?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's because of VS2015 or because it's an asp.net core project but this is an invalid element for me -- doesn't show up in intellisense and trying to use it creates an error saying the site can't be found.

Comment: I found this MSBUILD parameter that I've started using for CI. I haven't seen an error since I started using it... /p:EnableMSDeployAppOffline=true

Comment: Awesome! Another valuable setting not accessible by the UI. Love it!

Answer (score 12):

The [Azure App Service Deployment Task](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/AzureRmWebAppDeployment#azure-app-service-deployment-arm) has a checkbox for this (from version 2.0 onwards), under Additional Deployment Options: **Take App Offline**. Check that and you should be good to go.

> **Take Application Offline:** Select the option to take the AzureRM Web App offline by placing an app_offline.htm file in the root directory of the Web App before the sync operation begins. The file will be removed after the sync operation completes successfully.

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: What is this _New Azure Web App Deployment` component you speak of? Is this in Visual Studio 2015? is this a manual install for VS2015?

Comment: On Visual Studio Online web-site in your project go to "Build & Release" at the top, then select "Deploy AzureRM App Service" task on the left panel, on the right panel find and select "Take App Offline" option.

Comment: Is there a way to tell this option which file to use as app_offline.htm?  I'd like to style and customize it.  Thanks!

Comment: The link is dead.